# Using eval() to evaluate student programmers code. Security flaw?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express, socket.io

This is an express app where I am using CodeMirror to allow student programmers to write code in a glorified textarea. I'm using eval() to evaluate that code so that I can output a result for them. This result is passed to the server using socket.io and then returns to the client.

```
var codeInput = editor.getValue();
var result = eval(codeInput);
socket.emit('sendResult', result);
```

Is this safe to use? Does this compromise the security of my app any more than sending a user-submitted username or password or email?

Comment: Use `require('vm');`?

Comment: Have you considered just giving your students access to JSBin or JSFiddle or any similar service? They've already solved the problem you are trying to solve and are, quite frankly, always going to be better than your solution. Don't reinvent the wheel and so on, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of additional protection, this explicitly creates a [reflected cross-site scripting vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) in (most of) the applIcations hosted on the server *by design*.

If there is nothing else other than static content hosted on the site, and you can guarantee there never will be anything else on the site, then you only need to worry about what processing is done with the result (properly escaping the content before committing it to storage, properly escaping the content before displaying it).

i.e. this should have a dedicated vhost name.

Answer (score 0):

Improper use of eval can open up your application to injection attacks I guess would be the major issue here. So in short, yes, the security of your app will most certainly be compromised by using eval.

In addition, it'll be more difficult to debug as you'll have no visibility of line numbers, with performance hits on the top of that, too.

Out of interest, have you explored any other avenues?

Comment: @manbearpig1 I think it would be more sensible to then send the code string itself to the server via socket, run the eval() there, then send the result back. You could make that happen asynchronously too:

`setTimeout(function(){ eval(codeInput); }, 100);`

Comment: If I evaluate the input on the server and send the result back would that make it more safe?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context where the eval is executed, it could be very dangerous.

An fast compromise could be **execute the eval inside a sandboxed IFrame**.

[Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/static/demos/evalbox/index.html) a simple example, where

```
window.localStorage['sekrit']
```

is executed with just the "allow-scripts" permission (sandbox="allow-scripts").

I think all you need can be found in that page **source**.

More details and a list of other permission can be found [in this article.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/?redirect_from_locale=it)

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to use something like JSLint, instead of executing the code with eval.

JSLint will parse and analyses the source code and will returns it findings.
So you won't have any security issues.

[Here](http://jslint.com) you can see it in action.

Comment: JSLint only checks for syntactic errors - not semantic ones. It also enforces coding standards which are optional in the underlying language (albeit they are mostly considered good practice).

Comment: JSLint is just a linter, not a something that checks validity and correctness of programs. Moreover, it's very strict about what it deems acceptable throwing _code style_ errors among legitimate problems. JSHint and ESLint both allow for better rules. However, none of them will actually do proper checking: `var a = [1, 2, 3]; a[999];` is valid JavaScript code but it is most definitely not correct.